# web api validation ewrror

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api

I am doing velidation in web api but on one place I does not find any solution.

```
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Height")]
      [Range(0,999, ErrorMessage = "Height is too long")]
      [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Enter Only Numbers")]
      public Nullable<int> Height { get; set; }
```

here I am trying to use required validation for checking only integer but when I run this in rest client and give some string in place of height which is integer.

It's not giving the error message "Enter only number" in place of that its giving error:

> "Could not convert string to integer: d. Path 'Weight', line 9, position 12."

Comment: Hi, can you show us how is your controller and how are you sending the data?

Answer (score 0):

[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Fighters")]

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(tblFighters))]

    public IHttpActionResult createFighter(tblFighters tblFighters)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        bool usernameAlreadyExists = db.tblFighters.Any(x => x.FName == tblFighters.FName && x.LName == tblFighters.LName && x.DOB == tblFighters.DOB);

        if (ModelState.IsValid && usernameAlreadyExists == true)
        {


            return Ok("Fighter Already Exist");
        }
        else
            //for getting last user modification time 
            tblFighters.LastUserModified = DateTime.Now;
        //for authentication for getting modified user id
        //string currentuser = HttpContext.Current.Items["ID"].ToString();
        //tblFighters.ModifiedUserId = Convert.ToInt32(currentuser);
        db.tblFighters.Add(tblFighters);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = tblFighters.FighterID }, tblFighters);
    }
```

THIS ONE IS THE CONTROLLER AND ADVANCED REST CLIENT I AM POST THE DATA WITH SELECTING JSON FORMET AND DATA IS

{
FighterID: 1114182,
FName: "Bretffft",
LName: "Cooper",
Record: "9-2",
DOB: "1971-02-1322",
Age: 44,
Height: 72,
Weight: 185,
Reach: 83,
photo: "http://220.225.222.173/RingsideAdmin/Assets/fighterPhotos/fighterf4d7cc5f-52be-4566-8e87-b7398aee7788.jpg",
hometown: "Parts Unknown",
ModifiedUserId: 410,
ModifiedUser: "admin",
LastUserModified: "2015-08-14T19:17:37.977"
}
 IF I REMOVE HEIGHT VALUE AND PASS INTEGER ITS GIVING ERROR TO ME